# Can a multicast delegate in C# 4.0 be created from some sort of collection of method names?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm writing a simple game in XNA and I've faced a problem with delegates. I use them to represent physics in the game, e.g.:

```
public delegate void PhysicsLaw(World world);

//for gravitation
static public void BallLawForGravity(World world)
        {
            if (world.ball.position.Y != world.zeroLevel)
                //v(t) = v0 + sqrt(c * (h - zeroLevel))
                world.ball.speed.Y += (float)Math.Sqrt(0.019 * (world.zeroLevel - world.ball.position.Y)); 
        }
```

And I want to create multicast delegates for different objects/circumstances consisting from many methods such as `BallLawForGravity()`, but I can do it only like this:

```
processingList = BallLawForBounce;
processingList += BallLawForAirFriction;
...
processingList += BallLawForGravity;
```

Obviously, it doesn't look good. Is there any standard way to create a multicast delegate from collection of method names?

Comment: For now, why not try creating a separate handler `PerformPhysicsLaws(World world)` which just calls all the other methods you need?

Comment: I have several objects and I want to apply different laws to them - it's more, em, declarative as I think. I'm a functional programmer, so I like use function composition to express stuff, multicasting delegates here just emulates this way of thinking.

Comment: Why you've removed the accepted flag?

Comment: Why is "list = list + Bounce + Friction + Gravity;" unacceptable?

Comment: @Lakret: I don't understand. In what way is it a "hack"?  Would you say that "total = total + expenses + taxes + fees;" is also a "hack"?  Why is using the addition operator correctly a "hack"?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I think this is just slightly different cases. If I use construction like `list = list + Bounce + Friction + Gravity;` I usually assume that list is not "empty", otherwise it's not clear why I'm adding an empty list here. It's more a question of style and taste, I suppose.
Usage of addition is not "hack", but usage of addition of empty element to force type conversion looks like "hack" for me :)

Comment: @Lakret: You could cast the leftmost one to the desired delegate type and then the rest would follow via the left-associativity of addition.  list = (D)Bounce + Friction + Gravity;

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Oh, it looks well. I'm sooo foolish. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the static method [`Delegate.Combine Method (Delegate[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771.aspx) for such tasks.

```
 PhysicsLaw[] delegates = new PhysicsLaw[] {
        new PhysicsLaw( PhysicsLaw ),
        new PhysicsLaw( BallLawForAirFriction )
    };

    PhysicsLaw chained = (PhysicsLaw) Delegate.Combine( delegates );
    chained(world);
```

[More examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0180__delegate/DelegateCombine.htm).

**Update**
You can use the [creating delegate via Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx) for this but I don't recommend it, because it's very slow technic.

Comment: I've tried to use this method, but it takes delegates, not method names as parameters or I'm missing something. `new` before every method name don't look much better.
I'm using LINQ now: 

`public static PhysicsLaw MakeFromCollection(PhysicsLaw initial, 
params PhysicsLaw[] methods)
        {
            return methods.Aggregate(initial, (current, method) => current + method);
        }`

Comment: The OP is asking on how to assign the methods in one go which will form the invocation list of the delegate and not combine the lists of numerous delegates

Comment: @Lakret Sorry, didn't understand well. Unfortunately, you can't simply use the method names - only by Reflection, wich is heavy and slow solution

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you've declared

```
    public delegate void foo(int x);
    public static void foo1(int x) { }
    public static void foo2(int x) { }
    public static void foo3(int x) { }
```

Now you can combine them directly with `Delegate.Combine` if you don't mind typing the delegate name twice:

```
    foo multicast = (foo)Delegate.Combine(new foo[] { foo1, foo2, foo3 });
```

Or you can write a generic function to combine them if you don't mind typing the delegate name once:

```
    public static T Combine<T>(params T[] del) where T : class
    {
        return (T)(object)Delegate.Combine((Delegate[])(object[])del);
    }

    foo multicast2 = Combine<foo>(foo1, foo2, foo3);
```

Or you can write a non-generic function to combine them if you don't want to type the delegate name at all:

```
    public static foo Combine(params foo[] del)
    {
        return (foo)Delegate.Combine(del);
    }

    foo multicast3 = Combine(foo1, foo2, foo3);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's close to my solution, in projects where I won't use LINQ I will do like you suggest.

Comment: @Lankret: Why use LINQ when `Delegate.Combine` already does what you want?

Comment: because I've already changed many places in code :) But I've  already throw it away in the function and now use your solution.